# NSURLConnection non-closed stream

Tags: php, objective-c, sockets, nsurlconnection, inputstream

I have a PHP server that looks similar to this one:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Encoding: none;'); //disable apache compressed

ob_end_flush();
ob_start();
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(0);

while(true){

    echo ++$i.PHP_EOL;

    ob_flush();
    flush();

    usleep(250 * 1000);

}
```

This server never closes the connection, and flushes an incrementing number every quarter second. When opening this page in a browser, it works fine, and the content grows while the page is still loading. This page is served via HTTP.

**ATTEMPT #1, STRONGLY PREFERRED TO GET TO WORK**

I also have a class that is an NSURLConnection with a timeout set to 0 (it shouldn't have a timeout at all). That class gathers data using the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol; whenever the server sends data, the function `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data` is fired. This works excellently after a connection is closed; if there is a lot of data to be sent, one can track the progress very accurately.

In my case, however, the connection is not closed, and it never will be. Nevertheless, I would like to be notified of each flush. Currently, no method fires at all. The moment I set the PHP script to terminate after a certain period of time, and the connection closes, the data-received method is fired.

Therefore I was wondering: is there a way to be notified about every data transmission?

**ATTEMPT #2**

My next attempt was using NSInputStreams. I initiated them thus:

```
self.iStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/secuchat/lab/socket_test.php"]];
[self.iStream setDelegate:self];
[self.iStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.iStream open];
```

Yet alas, here, too, the function `- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode` is never fired.

Lastly, I would really prefer to somehow get it to work using the first method, for I would like to be able to send some data using POST, and raw sockets would make it much more difficult as opposed to libraries that already offer that function.

Comment: Just curious, why not just have your app ask for data on a scheduled timer instead of having your PHP dole out the data in an infinite cycle?

Comment: Because when on 3G connections, I don't want it sending a request to the server all the time. I thought having an open socket and pushing updates would be the more elegant solution, even though it's currently not really elegant on the server side.

Comment: This seems to be a topic of discussion on the [PHP `flush()` page](http://us2.php.net/flush). I must confess that I tried a few of those suggestions without too much luck, but it's probably worth taking a closer look at it.

Comment: @Rob: the server side does work. I tested it in different browsers, and it does flush every 0.25 seconds. It's the iOS client side that does not really work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the client is using a large buffer (e.g. 8kB) and you won't receive any message until that buffer is full. I don't know if it is possible to set the size of that buffer, but that may worth trying.